Proving that the Geometric Median is not invariant under affine transformations.
Let $\theta$ be the point which minimises the sum of Euclidean distances to $n$ given points $v_1,v_2,..,v_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then how do I show that this point is not invariant under affine transformations. To be more precise,
$$ \theta = \text{arg} \min_{v} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ||v-v_i|| $$
And
$f(X)=\text{A} X +b $ where $A$ is a $2×2$ matrix, $b= \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix} $ and $X$ is a point on the plane of the form $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $.
What we want to prove is that, generally,
$$ \text{arg} \min_{v} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ||v-f(v_i)|| = f \left( \text{arg} \min_{v} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ||v-v_i|| \right) $$
does not always hold.
I was at a bit of a loss on how to tackle the general case, so I tried to show that it does not hold for a special case of $n=3$. Consider three non-colinear points such that the angle at one of them is greater than or equal to $120°$, take the points $(\sqrt{3},0),(-\sqrt{3},0), (0,1)$, consider $b$= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} and $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\\ 1/\sqrt{3} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, it is readily observed that the above equality does not hold.
This is not very illuminating though. I would like an approach or a proof that shows this in a more general sense.

I am not really sure what you are asking. You showed that the median is not preserved under affine-linear maps by exposing a counterexample. What more are you looking for? A complete characterisation of maps that do preserve the median?

No, my question was aimed more towards an alternate method to showcase this, which is more general in nature than a mere counterexample. It is difficult to be precise here without knowing what such a method could be

How else would you disprove a statement of the form "For all families of points $(v_i)$ and all affine-linear maps $f$..." than giving a counterexample?

@Tzimmo The OP may be asking for an analysis of the places where affine invariance fails. Are they rare? Common? The single counterexample only shows the set is nonempty.

Like everyone else, I'm confused about what you expect, but here is an attempt.

Things are typically not invariant. Invariance is rare and requires a good reason to appear.

Your proof is perfectly valid: you have found a counter-example. I'm guessing that you are not satisfied with this single example because it doesn't give you a good intuition for what is going on.

The best intuition I have on this problem is that the components of the energy function: the individual $\theta \rightarrow ||v_i - \theta||$ are not invariant. Furthermore they cannot be decomposed (if they were squared, we would have invariance, no?). It's thus unsurprising that the min is unstable when everything is changing all over the place, isn't it?


I hope this helps.
